# Get Index Row Clicked in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I want the value of a field in a row that the user Clicked. i Write this code but this code Is wrong.

```js
var firstButtonColumnIndex = 0;
    grid = $('#list'), firstButtonColumnIndex, buttonNames = {};

grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
    datatype: 'local',
    direction: "rtl",
    datatype: 'json',
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['', ''],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'WorkOrderNo', width: 100, sortable: true },
        { name: 'AssetNo', width: 150, sortable: true },
        { name: 'WorkDescription', width: 400, sortable: true },
        { name: 'WorkOrderDate', width: 100, sortable: true },
        { name: 'WorkOrderTime', width: 100, sortable: true },
        { name: 'Remark', width: 260, sortable: true },
        { name: 'del', width: 20, sortable: false, search: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"
            }
        },
        { name: 'details', width: 20, sortable: false, search: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-document'></span>"
            }
        }
    ],
    gridview: true,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: '#pager',
    //  sortname: 'WorkOrderNo',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'asc',
    rownumbers: true,
    beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
        var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target);
        if (iCol >= 7) {
            alert("rowid=" + rowid + "\nButton name: " + buttonNames[iCol]);
        }
        // prevent row selection if one click on the button
        return (iCol >= firstButtonColumnIndex) ? false : true;
    }
});

buttonNames[7] = 'Remove';
buttonNames[8] = 'Details';
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false }, {}, {},
    {}, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 });
```

but in `beforeSelectRow` event `rowid` Always 0. i want return `WorkOrderNo` row clicked.

plese help me.
thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the code which you posted contains many small errors. So it can't work. If you modify your original code for the posting on the stackoverflow, please be more carefully in the modifications.

**For example:**

- `colNames` contains only two elements, but `colModel` - 8 elements. So one receive an error about the different length of the arrays and the code don't work more;
- You define `datatype` option twice: one with the value `'local'` and one more time with the value `'json'`;
- You should use comma (',') instead of semicolon (';') as the end of `firstButtonColumnIndex = 0` (see the first line). The current code use undefined `grid` and interpret it as the *global* variable.

**To your main question:**

You used "Get Index Row Clicked in jqGrid" as the title of your question, but you wrote in the text of your question that you have *`rowid` always 0 and not `rowIndex`*. To get the [rowIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp) you can modify the code of `beforeSelectRow` to the following:

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target);
    if (iCol >= 7) {
        alert("rowid=" + rowid +
              "\nrowIndex=" + $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow")[0].rowIndex +
              "\nButton name: " + buttonNames[iCol]);
    }
    // prevent row selection if one click on the button
    return (iCol >= firstButtonColumnIndex) ? false : true;
}
```

The information that you have always `rowid` as 0 follows to assumption that you fill wrong `id` in the JSON which produce the server code under `'jQGridHandler.ashx'`. The `id` have to have *unique* values over the page. You can use Developer Tools to examine the `id` attribute of the rows (the ids of `<tr>` elements of the grid) or to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to catch the JSON which will be returned from the server. If you would have problem to localize the error you should append your question with the JSON data.

Comment: Thanks for the help,but in this Jqgrid search isn't work.What I do not know why, plese help me. thanks

Comment: @mohsen: You are welcome! About your existing problem you should specify the problem more exactly. If you use `datatype: 'json'` then *the server* is responsible for the filtering (searching) of the data.  The server receive the `filters` parameter (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options) for the format). So the server should analyse the `filters` parameter and implement the searching.

Comment: :Sorry ,Do a search on the server side, or ClientSide???? I got all my Czech and all was right. I do not know how to solve.

Comment: @mohsen: If you use `datatype: 'json'` **the server side** is responsible to paging, sorting and **filtering**. The server construct WHERE part of the SELECT to the database based on the `filters` parameter. If you do want that *client side*  implement paging and filtering the server should return *the whole* data independent on the values of `rows` and `page` input parameters. You should add `loadonce: true` to the jqGrid and be careful in defining `sorttype` column option. If you don't define any `sorttype` property the grid will interpret the data as "text".

Comment: i Want Implement Search in ClientSide.

Comment: @mohsen: Then add `loadonce: true` option first of all and return all data to the client in the server response.

Comment: @mohsen: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ Oleg:When data are loaded in this case? When all the data load in Formload??? thanks

Comment: @mohsen: Which case? What you mean under the "the data load in Formload"? Please just add `loadonce: true` option in your current jqGrid code and try to filter the data. Works the code now better as before? What is still the problem now?

Comment: @ Oleg: Hi, if in Table Have 2 PK, How set id and How Give in value for use in jqgrid???  thanks

Comment: @mohsen: The problem is that the most of your questions is very difficult to understand. You asked about "Table". Do you mean database table or HTML table. Database table can have PK (primary key), but only **one** PK per table. HTML table and all it's elements (rows for example) can have ids but not PKs. Then you wrote about "setting" of ids and "giving in value" which I can't interpret in any way. It's better if you ask new question and describe in details what you want.

Comment: I Want get All Data When Row Clicked